# How i can update junction table automatically and access data from junction table?

Tags: php, mysql

Now I have 2 tables: `demo`(detailed information about users) and `users`(login and password), then I create a `junction table`(ID, demo_ID and user_ID).
The system working like this:

1. User register
2. User login
3. User fill form where he gave a detailed information

And I want to fill junction table automatically with `user_ID` and `demo_ID` where user_ID will LOGGED USER and `demo_ID` the information of exactly this user.

How can I do this? Please help me =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use query like -

INSERT INTO rel_users_demo (demo_ID,users_ID) SELECT demo.ID, users.ID join on demo.EMail = users.email

You have not mentioned which column you have in common(foreign key) between demo and users. you can keep your column at place of xx and yy.

Comment: here in our table one variable is unique and COMMON and it is E-MAIL

Comment: Yes, in query there syntax errors so i don't know how to handle them: INSERT INTO rel_users_demo (rel_ID, demo_ID,users_ID) VALUES (SELECT demo.ID AND users.ID join on demo.EMail = users.email)

Comment: Set your rel_ID is auto incremented primary key, and try this query

Comment: Where rel_ID is autoincremented

Comment: In your rel_users_demo, you need to use rel_ID is primary ke and set it as autoincremented key

Comment: It was already done, can u check your query and send me one more time without syntax errors

Comment: Oh I see that u edited your answer))) But when I compile it there is :#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'join on demo.EMail = users.email' at line 1